# Cannot set select option with javascript when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

I am using jQuery. I have a select tag in my page.

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

I get some value from my server with ajax while loading the page.

```
$().ready(function() {
  $.post(url, function(result) {
    var value = result.value; // for example, result can be {value: "1"}.
    console.log($("#sel")[0].options.length); // output: 0 // EMPTY options ??
    $("#sel").val(value);
  });
});
```

But my selected option does not change.
The select tag seems to have no options in it.
Shouldn't the DOM have been already fully loaded in that context?

I can set the selected option when the page is loaded and the user fires some actions.

Comment: Where is `value` defined? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @scunliffe: It does not matter. The point is that in that context the select tag seems to contain no options at all.

Comment: @Cattla : It does not matter. It won't work even if I set `value` to a string directly.

Comment: try `$("#sel option").length` in your console log.

Comment: @roullie: It prints 0. I find out where goes wrong. The options are also loaded with ajax response when the page is loaded.

Comment: What you want to do is set the `selected` attribute on the _option_ that corresponds to the `var value = result.value` that you retrieve, _*not*_ set the "value" of the select control itself.

Comment: @Richard: i see.  when do you populate the options in the select? try putting it before you set the selected value

Answer (score 0):

Try this Variation, this should work as you may have wanted it to.

Im Assuming the resultValue is an index of an option of the select.

```
$().ready(function() {
  $.post(url, function(result) {
    var resultValue = result.value; // for example, result can be {value: "1"}.
    var select = $('#sel');
    var opts = $(select[0].options).toArray();
    console.log(opts); // output will be the number of child nodes within the Select

    // Setting the new value of the select, based on the result.value
    select.val(opts[resultValue].value); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $.post(url, function(result) {
    var value = result.value; 

    $("#sel option[value="+value+"]").attr("selected", true);
  });
```